# Spring bean set destroy method on collection

Tags: java, spring

I have Map as bean in configuration class and need to provide Spring destroy method for all map values:

```
@Configuration
public class ProducerConfiguration  {
    @Bean("producers")
    public Map<String, Producer> producers() { ... }
}
```

Reason that above bean looks like a collection is creating producers dynamically based on external config file.
For bean without a collection it can be easily done with **destroyMethod** attribute on `@Bean` annotation:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
public Producer producer() { ... }
```

Is it possible somehow to provide destroy method on collection bean? As a workaround, I can create a separate class which just wrap a collection and has a close method, but I don't want to create classes for each collection bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible if you inject your map into each `Producer` and `Producer.close()` will remove given producer from the map.

But new class (that contains map instance and  destroy method) looks as best solution to me. Your custom class may use generics, so internal map field will be `Map<String, ? extends Closeable>`. You will not need separate class for `Map<String, Something>, Map<String, SomethingElse>` etc

I would use that class as only way to register new Producers. Map class has more methods that you really need. For example it supports removing keys without calling `close` on the value for that key. With custom class will be able to properly enforce business rule 'Producer that is closed is removed from registration map'

Comment: thank you. in my case `Producer` is not owned by me, so I can't update code inside it. I decided to go with your suggestion about new generic class